# Ionic2 build for iOs fails

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to set up an Ionic2 environment following the instructions given in the Installation section of the official 'Getting Started' Ionic2 documentation.

I am on a Mac with El Captain version 10.11.5 and the latest xCode version (7.3.1) installed.

I have run the command `ionic platform add ios` successfully after having installed Cordova.

When I run the next command `ionic emulate ios` (as mentioned in the getting started guide) I get a mysterious error whose log is

```
(node:38155) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.

Running 'emulate:before' gulp task before emulate
[18:17:00] Starting 'clean'...
[18:17:00] Finished 'clean' after 45 ms
[18:17:00] Starting 'build'...
[18:17:00] Starting 'sass'...
[18:17:00] Starting 'html'...
[18:17:00] Starting 'fonts'...
[18:17:00] Starting 'scripts'...
[18:17:00] Finished 'html' after 80 ms
[18:17:00] Finished 'scripts' after 78 ms
[18:17:00] Finished 'fonts' after 88 ms
[18:17:01] Finished 'sass' after 901 ms
[18:17:07] Finished 'build' after 6.73 s
[18:17:07] Starting 'emulate:before'...
[18:17:07] Finished 'emulate:before' after 4.22 μs


You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.

Running command: /Users/enrico.piccinin/work/dbs/examples/ionic2/cutePuppyPics/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/enrico.piccinin/work/dbs/examples/ionic2/cutePuppyPics


add to body class: platform-ios

Error: 


Caught exception:
 undefined
```

Then I surf a bit and find a suggestion to run the following command `npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true` but once I do it this is what I obtain

```
> ios-deploy@1.8.6 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ios-deploy-298c9491
> ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ios-deploy-298c9491/src/scripts/check_reqs.js:29
        var ver = arr[1];
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/ios-deploy-298c9491/src/scripts/check_reqs.js:29:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:492:12)
npm ERR! Darwin 15.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ios-deploy" "--unsafe-perm=true"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! ios-deploy@1.8.6 preinstall: `./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ios-deploy@1.8.6 preinstall script './src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ios-deploy package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./src/scripts/check_reqs.js && xcodebuild
```

By the way, building for Android works fine on the same machine.

Any idea of what can be wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to run the project from XCode?
On mac when I want to run the application I run from terminal: ionic build ios and after that, I run the project from XCode. Everything works fine